# Heroku deployment with nest js project

Tags: heroku, nestjs

I have github account which is connnected with my heroku account. I am trying to deploy code through heroku and my project is also connected with heroku pipeline. Build is getting succeeded. But getting error while accessing app

Heroku logs

```html
2022-09-07T10:08:37.346556+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-09-07T10:08:41.005367+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-09-07T10:08:41.005458+00:00 app[web.1]: > food-court@0.0.1 start
2022-09-07T10:08:41.005458+00:00 app[web.1]: > nest start
2022-09-07T10:08:41.005459+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-09-07T10:08:41.020373+00:00 app[web.1]: /tmp/start-7b018378.sh: 1: nest: not found
2022-09-07T10:08:41.187916+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2022-09-07T10:08:41.284101+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-09-07T10:13:07.218759+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=food-court-be-dev.herokuapp.com request_id=52c79661-a554-4c2b-b412-c24429d538c5 fwd="103.181.100.29" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-09-07T10:13:07.784604+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=food-court-be-dev.herokuapp.com request_id=f1a47ec4-6160-47d2-80ef-a0db2569d7bf fwd="103.181.100.29" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

resolved issue by changing "start": "nest start", to "start": "node dist/main.js" in package.json